# How to Render Rigid Body Physics

Tags: rendering, physics, bezier-curves

all,

Me again. I am trying to render an animation with rigid body physics. I have baked the animation to keyframe, and when I render individual images of particular frames the animation looks A-OK. However, when I try to render the animation as a video all of the images are the same. Any ideas how to fix this? You can see the Blender file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1312U5OxQWMN1OYdCE2HPEHFYxstRbub1

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The problem stemmed from me having ticked the dynamic property in rigid body settings for each object. Unticking dynamic worked.